# Could anyone prove this result from Deutsch's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Does anyone know how to prove the result shown in one of the images, that $$U_f(\left|x\right>(\left|0\right>-\left|1\right>)/\sqrt{2} = (-1)^{f(x)}\left|x\right>(\left|0\right> - \left|1\right>)/\sqrt{2}~ ?$$ The desired action of $U_f$ is shown in the image of a quantum circuit. This example is taken from Nielsen and Chuang's Quantum Computation and Quantum Information.
[image: Diagram of Quantum Circuit]
[image: Result of Gate action]

Comment: Where's your effort???

Comment: I have no idea where to even start. I guess my problem is with setting out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your first scan, $U_f$ maps $\lvert x\rangle \lvert y\rangle$ to $\lvert x\rangle \lvert y \oplus f(x)\rangle,$ where the range of $f$ (a function with a 1 bit domain range) is $\{0,1\}.$ Applying it to your input state $\lvert x\rangle (\lvert 0\rangle - \lvert 1\rangle)$ we get $\lvert x\rangle (\lvert f(x)\rangle - \lvert 1\oplus f(x)\rangle),$ which if $f(x)=0$ yields $\lvert x\rangle (\lvert 0\rangle - \lvert 1 \rangle)$ and $\lvert x\rangle (\lvert 1\rangle - \lvert 0 \rangle)$ if $f(x)=1,$ both can be abbreviated as $(-1)^{f(x)} \lvert x\rangle (\lvert 0\rangle - \lvert 1\rangle).$

Answer (score 1):

- Show that the bottom wire is in the state $|0\rangle - |1\rangle$.
- Show that applying an X gate to that state negates its amplitude.
- Show that *conditionally* applying an X gate to that state negates the amplitude of *the control*. That is to say, states causing the X to be applied have their amplitudes negated but states that don't apply the X are left alone.
- Show that $(-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle$ means "negate state $x$ if $f$ is satisfed by $x$"
- Put it all together

Personally, I find the diagram clearer when the big $U$ is cut into its input and output parts. So here's that:

[image: Equivalent circuit]